# gnome-session-wayland not found in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, package, repository, gnome, wayland

I am trying to install the wayland session on gnome 40.5 and to do so they say to install the package gnome-session-wayland but as soon as I try to install it on Ubuntu 21.10 I get an error saying that the package could not be found and this is not normal given that the package should be present in the ubuntu repository, I searched all over for this problem but found nothing about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, evidently on ubuntu wayland is automatically disabled if you are using an nvidia driver as the support from nvidia on wayland is still poor today but there is still a way to force the use of wayland by seeing here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369250/how-do-i-enable-wayland-on-ubuntu-21-10-nvidia